# Вытащить из Hash элементы

Tags: ruby

Почему, когда вытаскиваю элемент из Hash, пишет nil. Что имеем:

```
{"3"=>{"Серебристый"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}}, 
"17"=>{"Серебристо-зеленый"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil,}, 
       "Золотой"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil,}, 
       "Алюминий"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}, 
       "Зеленый"=>{"url"=>nil, "hex"=>"009500"}, 
       "Красный"=>{"url"=>nil, "hex"=>"F61A1A"},
       "Бежевый"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil,},
       "Черный"=>{"url"=>nil, "hex"=>"0B0B0B"},
        "Синий"=>{"url"=>nil, "hex"=>"0000DF"}}, 
"30"=>{"Серебристый"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}, 
       "Золотой"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}, 
       "Хром"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}, 
       "Хром"=>{"url"=>"/../.png", "hex"=>nil}}}
```

Сам Hash c именем STRICT_COLOR. Мне нужно вытащить цвета, соответственно, если, нет их в hex , взять их из url.Пытаюсь вытащить так:

```
STRICT_COLOR[group.id.to_s][value]["hex"]   или
STRICT_COLOR[group.id.to_s][value]["url"]
```

Не получается...пишет nil в обоих, может что-то не так делаю. Т.к параллельно изучаю язык.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей, что в group.id и что в value? Прямо выведите их в консоль (при помощи puts или Rails.logger.info).

Comment: group.id = @tovar.parent.id - id товара, value = picker_data[0] - значение,которое мы берем из массива типа ["Алюминий", [["000097897", "000098090"]]]

Comment: Не может там быть вместо "Алюминий" чего-нибудь вроде "%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9"?

Comment: Точно нет, проверил все значения, получаем четкое указание на элемент хэша STRICT_COLOR["16375"]["Алюминий"]["url" или "hex"]

Comment: Может быть,конечно, в самой базе и url  и hex = nil

Comment: Да,проблема в базе...К сожалению.

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу тут несколько вариантов решения:

1. исключить из структуры ключ если значение `nil`. И просто сделать выбор одного ключа
2. сделать выбор по значению не `nil`.Может прийдется добавить `.first`

`STRICT_COLOR['3']['Серебристый'].values.compact`